# Not Getting standard boot countdown screen in Dualboot (Linux 6.2 & Windows 8)

Tags: linux, rhel, dual-boot

**Problem** I have installed (Dual Booted) Red Hat 6.2 on a Windows machine ,In windows boot manager it is not showing Linux ,its only showing windows 8 . I am pressing arrow keys but only windows 8 is coming. Any solution to it help me out?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is the place for Linux/Unix, I suggest your thrash away the windows bootloader, and install grub from Linux distribution. BTW, RHEL 6.2 is way too old. Switch to newer ones unless you are limited by a license. Latest is 6.5, though Their 7 beta is out. To install grub and update,

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

It might be grub2-mkconfig if your grub version is 2.